# How to manage possible Token Expiration while running long Tasks using CSOM

Tags: c#, sharepoint, access-token, csom

On my App I'm getting the access token using the MSAL package and then add it to the context like sample below:

```
using var clientContext = new ClientContext(oSite.Url);

    clientContext.ExecutingWebRequest += (sender, e) =>
    {
    e.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + rootSiteAccessToken;
    };
```

With this context then I get the files on each library and iterate through them make the needed changes.

At the moment I got stuck on getting the files; after 500k items I got access denied. I imagine this is due the token expiration. I'm doing more test for confirming this scenario, but I will definitely have this issue at some moment because the main library has 3M files. Although I'm getting the files and processing them by batches to don't run out of memory, I expect the Task will need to run for few days.

I wonder, which would be the best practice on this situation to not falling on access denied due Token expiration.

Using PnP PowerShell I have run scripts that run for weeks. But I haven't been able to get clarity from its code on how they manage the interactive credentials.

Also, if anyone has a good recommendation on how to collect 3M files efficiently it would be awesome.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Token is two steps 1) Get token 2) Send token with each request.  Are you sending the token with each request?

Comment: I add the token to the client context, then I use the context to get the items. I can get 500k items, but then it failed because Access Denied.

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72748113/why-am-i-getting-error-access-denied-after-successful-interactive-authentication At top it says "Accounts in the msal cache: 1".

Comment: I think that case is different. That one seems using MSAL and adding the token to the Graph package. The root cause posted by the user, it was a Access token permissions. While on my case I have the correct permissions, but a long running task make the token to expire.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint API allows auto-renewal of the tokens. You can just enable auto-renewal for your app. For that, you need to **grant the 'offline_access' permission** to your app (and use it when you create CSOM client, i.e. request this scope). That should do it. CSOM renews the token automatically if you have granted this permission to your app.

Comment: May I know how to grant the 'offline_access' to the app in Azure AD? I don't see this part explained anywhere.

I tried just adding the scopes durng the request, but it doesn't work.
 I'm using MSAL to get the access token. I'm sending my request to "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize" and as scope I addd "https://{domain}.sharepoint.com/.defaultsiteUrl openid offline_access".
When I check the scopes of the token "offline_access" is not there.

Comment: If you just add this scope to the request, and then consent to it when logging in, that should be enough. You can check if you have it by looking at the list of scopes your token has: https://jwt.io/

Comment: I found the permission "offline_access", it was inside the Graph API section. I granted the permissions and content as Admin. Still the Access Token comes without the "offline_acces" permission. Even if that is the only scope I added while getting the Access Token. There is one additinal configuration I am missing that I haven't figurate out yet.